Show that $f(X)$ is universally measurable if $X$ is universally measurable
Let $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a universally measurable set and $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ a measurable function. How can I show that $f(X)$ is universally measurable?

On the paper "On Perfect Measures" by V.V. Sazonov, we have the following result: $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is universally measurable iff every finite Borel measure on $\mathfrak{B}(X)$ is perfect. I'm trying to use this result to prove that $f(X)$ is universally measurable, but I'm stuck.
Please, give me a hint. I also posted this question on math.stackexchange but I didn't receive any answer.

EDIT:
I know the following result that may be helpful.

Let $(X,\Sigma)$ be a countably generated measurable space. If every finite measure $\mu
 :\Sigma \to \mathbb{R}$ is perfect, then $f(X)$ is universally
measurable for all measurable functions $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying
$\Sigma =\{f^{-1}(B):B\in\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$.


Why do you think it is true?  Was it stated in a book or paper?

It's (a particular case) of the exercise 451X.(k) of the book "Measure Theory" by Fremlin.

In that exercise in Fremlin's book, $f$ is a Borel measurable function from a larger Polish space, not from the universally measurable set in question.

But every Borel measurable function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ has a Borel measurable extension $\hat f: \mathbb{R}\to\ \mathbb{R}$. This a consequence of the Kuratowski Extension Theorem.

It seems one has to appeal to a measurable selection theorem (one of those in Bogachev's "Measure Theory", section 6.9), to show that every measure on the range of $f$ is the image of a measure on its domain.

@user95282 We can obtain the desired result if we show that for all finite Borel measure $\nu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ there is a finite Borel measure $\mu$ on $X$ such that $\nu=\mu\circ f^{-1}$. I’m trying to find an appropriate version of the 433D Theorem of Fremlin.

The conditions given are likely insufficient.
Suppose ν is a perfect measure on X, and f is a measurable function. Then the image measure f(ν) is a perfect measure on R. This tells us that for any Borel set B ⊆ R, we can “approximate” the measure of f(ν) with another Borel set B' ⊆ B, i.e., (f(ν))(B') ≈ (f(ν))(B).
However, this does not directly tell us how to approximate the set f(X) itself with a Borel set. We know that (f(ν))(B) = ν(f⁻¹(B)), but this does not provide a constructive method to find a Borel set B'' such that μ(f(X) Δ B'') = 0, where μ is an arbitrary Borel measure on R.
We cannot, based solely on the perfectness of f(ν), establish a direct connection between f(X) and some Borel set such that they are “sufficiently close” under all Borel measures.
The consideration of all Borel measures is necessary:
The definition of universally measurable requires it to hold for all Borel measures μ. When we consider a perfect measure ν on X, we are actually only considering the image measure f(ν) induced by ν. This is just one Borel measure among many on R. We cannot infer from the perfectness of f(ν) that there exists a suitable Borel set to approximate f(X) for all Borel measures.
However, in some special cases, such as:
In a standard Borel space, if a set is measurable with respect to a complete perfect measure, then
If (X, Σ) is a standard Borel space (e.g., any Polish space equipped with its Borel σ-algebra), and μ is a complete measure on X, then if a set A ⊂ X is measurable with respect to μ, and μ is perfect, then A must be universally measurable.
Additionally, I have a simple proof:
Let (X, B(X)) be a Polish space, and f: X → R be a measurable function (i.e., for any B ∈ B(R), we have f⁻¹(B) ∈ B(X)). Define g: X → R×R, g(x) = (x, f(x)).
Proof of the measurability of g: For any B₁, B₂ ∈ B(R), we have g⁻¹(B₁×B₂) = B₁ ∩ f⁻¹(B₂) ∈ B(X), therefore g is measurable.
According to a corollary of the measurable graph theorem: Γf = g(X) is an analytic subset of R×R. Since the projection map π: R×R → R, π(x, y) = y is continuous, and the image of an analytic set under a continuous map is an analytic set, therefore f(X) = π(Γf) is an analytic set.
All analytic sets are universally measurable, therefore f(X) is universally measurable.

It seems I have overthought this; in a standard Borel space, it is entirely feasible.

Could please see my edit? Maybe it can help!
